# What happens when a user closes their browser waiting for a long running web service call?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, biztalk

I have a similar issue like here:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/biztalkgeneral/thread/87d5a6ec-04ee-4c6f-8267-f526ee105f0b

I have an asp.net web page that calls a BizTalk web service.  The BizTalk orchestration does its stuff and returns a response to the asp.net page.  The process could take up to a minute or two.  I get a lot of timeouts but it seems the BizTalk orchestration is returning within 30 seconds on average.

I'm wondering, what happens if the user submits their request and then immediately closes their browser.  Does the asp.net client stop waiting for BizTalk's request (and cause a timeout) or will it still wait for the request even if the user has closed their browser?

Comment: I was wondering this myself, actually...

Comment: I was wondering too.  My gut is that the server will have no way of knowing, but maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: I believe the server runs the call and if the returning client is no longer available it drops the data. So it basically runs into a timeout (from within the server itself) or drops the data when the data is available. Not 100% on it though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The ASP.NET request continues to execute, ignorant of the fact that the browser that originally submitted the GET/POST is no longer waiting. The request will complete, barring any other errors, such as server timeouts.

Comment: The behaviour depends on whether the browser and the server are both configured for keepalive. If the client disconnects the socket, the server will shut down the session, aborting execution.